# Test, if I don't want to trigger the whole thing

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test

A Spring Boot application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@Slf4j
public class MyApplication {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

  ...
  @Bean
  public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
     ...
     // read data from a file and publishing an event
  }
}
```

For an integration test, I have something typical.

```
@SpringBootTest
public class TestingMyApplicationTests{
   ...
}
```

After I start a test case in the class, the whole chain events occurs, that is reading a file, publishing events and an event listener acts accordingly.

What is the best approach to avoid such chain events occur during running a test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid that the whole Spring Context is started for all of your integration tests, you can take a look at other test annotations that create a [sliced context](https://rieckpil.de/spring-boot-test-slices-overview-and-usage/):

- `@WebMvcTest` creates a Spring Context with only MVC related beans
- `@DataJpaTest` creates a Spring Context with only JPA/JDBC related beans
- etc.

In addition to this, I also would remove your `CommandLineRunner` from your main entry Spring Boot entry point class. Otherwise also the annotations above would trigger the logic.

Therefore you can outsource it to another `@Component` class:

```
@Component
public class WhateverInitializer implements CommandLineRunner{

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

   // ...

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
     ...
     // read data from a file and publishing an event
  }


}
```

Apart from this you can also use `@Profile("production")` on your Spring beans to only populate them when a specific profile is active. This way you can either include or exluce them for all your integration tests if you don't want e.g. this startup logic always.

Comment: Thanks very much for your input. The logic I need to write test is the core part of the application. Logically speaking, none of  those sliced context would be applicable. I guess that I still need one of them so that I can do tests on the functionality. I possibly shall set up a profile for test so that it won't load the component you illustrate.

Comment: Just a minor correction for the future reference, the commandLineRunner needs to be implemented as a component such as MyCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner{...}.